# Previewing secrets from Secrets Manager in my ECS cluster?

Tags: amazon-ecs

My ECS task definition has plenty of these:

```
{
    "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:xxx:secret:/xxx",
    "name": "secret"
}
```

However, I am running into some issues with variables. I went into Secrets Manager, double checked the secrets I imported, and dev team agrees they look fine. But, the app we deployed still complains about some variables. They can't check them on their side, and I'm not sure how to check them on mine. What's my course of action here?

Comment: I would start by editing your question to include the actual error message, or details about any unexpected behavior. When you say your app "complains about some variables" that isn't clear enough for us to understand what is happening. What is a "complaint" in this context exactly? Show the full details in your question.

Comment: @MarkB I mean, it throws variable specific errors, for example, it can't connect to a 3rd party service because the API key provided is bad. I just want to see what API key it's reading.

Comment: If there are no errors being thrown by ECS related to reading the secrets, then this just sounds like an issue with the value of the secret. You could use `ecs exec` to get into the container and view the environment variables. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html Otherwise, you would have add some debug logging to your application to log the value of those variables.